# Can a person be marked by multiple Horrors?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

**Can a person be marked by multiple Horrors in Earthdawn** (1st ed.)**?**

Or... does a single mark give access to the person to *any* Horror that "sees" it?

(Yes, this is a straight to the point Q.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Horror Marks are specific to individual Horrors.

Check out the **Horrors supplement for ED 1**, pages 97-99 for a description of Horror Marks, and especially the title Unique Horror Marks on page 97.

Also, check out the Suppress Horror Mark power on page 103, which mentions explicitly that Horrors have their own marks.

The Horror stalker talent Bear Mark also support this, as it allows adepts to safely isolate Horror Marks of specific Horrors, from among all the Marks of all the Horrors affecting the character. It has nothing to do with bears, though. :)

My thoughts on this: The Horror Mark is a magical connection between the individual Horror and the poor marked sod (or the poor Horror and the marked stalker). Other horrors will mot sense it from afar (only when in line of sight). Of course, when a different Horror sees the character, physically or through raw magic, it may also add its own Mark.

Answer (score 6):

A single Namegiver can be marked by multiple Horrors.

Horror marks are incredibly difficult to "see", even for other Horrors.

The exception is, of course, the Named Horror Buualgathor introduced in *Parlainth* that rides Horror marks from the victim to the Horror. The Horror-marked individual rarely survives, same with the Horror on the other end.

Answer (score 5):

I do believe that each Horror mark is unique to that Horror.  Otherwise, the [Horror Stalker discipline](http://pandagaminggrove.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/earthdawn-anatomy-of-discipline-08.html) would be grossly overpowered since they use the Horror mark as a way to track an individual Horror.  Besides, I never saw Horror as playing nice between themselves.

Comment: +1 This is in line with my games and memory; although I don't have the book to hand.